# Accessing files through picker for users who have not yet enabled Drive

Tags: picker, google-drive-api

I am running into a difficulty with the picker api for users who have installed our Chrome Web Store app, but who have not yet enabled drive. For users in this state, it is possible to save new files using the files/insert api, which returns a successful response, but these files do not show up in picker. Once the user enables drive, all the files they have previously saved begin showing up in picker.

Is this behavior intended? If so, what is the best way to determine if a user has drive enabled, so that we can prompt users to enable drive instead of making it look like we're not saving their documents?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the picker and the API will only work if the user has installed your Drive application ont he Chrome webs Store.

We understand the pain involved for developers and we are looking to relax this restriction.

In the mean time there is a way to check if the user has installed the Drive app, for that you need an OAuth 2.0 access token (so your user will need to have gone through the OAuth flow and authorized you to access his Drive data). Then you can simply try to read a file with a bogus ID (lets say ID "000" or "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw"). If the API returns the error ["403: The authenticated user has not installed the app with client id {clientId}"](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#403_the_authenticated_user_has_not_installed_the_app_with_client_id_clientid), that means that he has not installed the app yet and that you should hide Drive functionnalities and probably show him something that say "To take advantage of our latest Google Drive integration/features, we recommend that you install our Drive App *link to Chrome Web Store listing*".
If the user has your Drive app installed you will get a ["404: File not found: {fileId}"](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#404_file_not_found_fileid) error on this request.

Comment: You're missing a distinction that tripped me up too. My question is regarding users who have installed our CWS app, but who have not yet enabled drive at drive.google.com. You answered a different, but good question: "what should I do for users who haven't installed my CWS app?" but I meant to ask, "what should I do for users who haven't enabled drive yet?"

Comment: Oops sorry, I should have probably just read better ^^ I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 1):

First it is odd that the picker is not showing files for your non-drive enabled user.

So I just tested the picker with a non-drive account and everything worked as expected... For instance you can try with the Balsamiq Drive app https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pplbmgaodhjmbklkgkgmlghaekcfhhkk They are using the picker in Mockup > Open...

After installing you have to go to https://balsamiqgdrive.appspot.com

I created a mockup first and saved it. It appeard in Docs. Then I tried the picker in Balsamiq and I could see it.

Comment: That's interesting. We're at https://www.desmos.com/drive/calculator so you can see the behavior I'm talking about (if you visit as a user that has the CWS app installed, but does not have drive enabled). Could it be a difference between shortcuts and documents? I see that balsamic is using .bmml files, whereas we are using shortcuts with the mime type application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.216942115270

Comment: That could be it. Could you give me a step by step  way to reproduce this so I can file a bug internally?

Comment: Sure thing.

1) Get yourself a google account that doesn't have drive enabled
2) Install Graphing Calculator by Desmos.com at the Chrome Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bhdheahnajobgndecdbggfmcojekgdko
3) Launch the app, and save a graph using the "save & share" button
4) Click the "my graphs" button, which will pop up an empty picker
5) (Optionally) enable drive for your test user, and note that the graph you previously saved now appears in the picker.

Comment: Yes I can reproduce. Very strange though: if you use the search feature embedded in the picker the matching graph will be displayed.

Comment: Filed the bug, lets hope for the best :)